# Dev Container is not starting in VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-10

Hi Guys I'm trying to open the dev container from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-cpp and I get an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvU3x.png) when creating it.

It is also saying that this command is failing:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount type=bind,source=c:/Users/jnvie/vscode-remote-try-cpp,target=/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-cpp,consistency=cached -l vsch.quality=stable -l vsch.local.folder=c:\Users\jnvie\vscode-remote-try-cpp -l vsch.remote.devPort=0 -u vscode --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-vscode-remote-try-cpp-a8dfd3c1511c138f783ff7d36d26f76c -c echo Container started ;  while sleep 1; do :; done
```

with this error message:

```
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
Run: docker run -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount type=bind,source=c:/Users/jnvie/vscode-remote-try-cpp,target=/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-cpp,consistency=cached -l vsch.quality=stable -l vsch.local.folder=c:\Users\jnvie\vscode-remote-try-cpp -l vsch.remote.devPort=0 -u vscode --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-vscode-remote-try-cpp-a8dfd3c1511c138f783ff7d36d26f76c -c echo Container started ;  while sleep 1; do :; done
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Drive sharing failed for an unknown reason.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

My system is running windows 10 pro and I previously had docker toolbox running before I upgraded and got docker desktop for windows

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that issue before I ran into the issue I'm on now.  I had to authorize the directory for access, but there are a handful of caveats that you might run into.
This article covered a lot of them for me: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/